# Sprite-Kit tutorial and sample game project

Tags: iphone, sprite-kit

Where can I find good Sprite-Kit tutorial and sample game project? Searched in google but not getting any sample game. Wish to get some API reference also.

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about a framework under NDA.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can find Sprite-Kit-Tutorial Here : [**Sprite Kit Programming Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/SpriteKit_PG/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Sprite-Kit Sample Game: [**Adventure**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/AdventureArchitecture/AdventureArchitecture.html)

Adventure demonstrates how to build a relatively complex game using Sprite Kit.

**Other non-apple sprit-kit tutorial**:

Raywenderlich : **[Spritekit-tutorial-for-Beginners](http://www.raywenderlich.com/42699/spritekit-tutorial-for-beginners)**

Codefellows: [Simple Sprite-Kit Game Tutorial](https://www.codefellows.org/blogs/simple-sprite-kit-game-tutorial-part1)

Comment: The Adventure game sample project link: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/CodeExplainedAdventure/AdventureArchitecture/AdventureArchitecture.html

Comment: The following tutorial will teach you how to use the Sprite Kit framework to create a simple Airplanes game. Along the way, you’ll learn all the core concepts of Sprite Kit: animations, emitters, collision detection, and more! http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/build-an-airplane-game-with-sprite-kit-project-setup/ and the the following link explains sprite kit from very basic http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/09/how-i-went-from-0-to-game-with-sprite-kit/